# Links to Network Shares not opening in Outlook for Desktop for some users

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-explorer, shared-folders, hyperlink

I've found a few of these questions but each thread has gone dead without a solution being found.

We have seen multiple cases in our organisation where users can't use shared network file paths. They add the link to an Outlook email but when some users click the link Outlook just shows the 3 dots moving at the top then either stops without opening the file or gives an "The file could not be found" error.

The folders being linked to are accessible by everyone in the organisation - it's just the link that's breaking. Unusually, the links also don't work only for some users, not all.

The links are being setup correctly, access is correct, everyone uses the same version of Outlook on Windows 11... I can't see a difference that may be causing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions at all?

Many thanks.

Replies to comments:
There is spaces in the file path where there is spaces in the folder names. There are no double quotes. Copying the file path into file explorer works.
Hostnames I believe. Link looks like this: \IP ADDRESS\NETWORK DRIVE NAME\Folders\File.filetype
The users can currently access the network drive - I've seen cases where the network drive is open in File Explorer and the links still fail.

Comment: do the paths have spaces in them? when the unc path was entered was it wrapped in double quotes? if you then paste that path into explorer does it work?

Comment: also are the server names fqdn's, or just hostnames?

Comment: Is this a UNC path that's been linked or a network drive path? If it's a network drive, has the user checked that they're currently able to access that network drive via Explorer first? If the network drive is inactive (for instance the machine's just started) some apps will trying reaching the destination file such that it causes the drive to connect, but I've seen some others that will fail if it's not immediately accessible. Eg if you manually try accessing the network drive to wake it up, you then find the app is able to access the path.

Comment: What if checking the email and clicking the link from the web mail?
Does it work if the users in question manually copy the link in Outlook email and then paste it to the windows file explorer? This helps narrow down if the issue does involve the Outlook client?

Comment: Have answered the comments above in the original post - thanks everyone.

Comment: if there are spaces and you didn't carefully put doublequotes around the path while you were typing/pasting it in (they disappear after outlook realizes its a link), then the link is probably malformed and only goes up to the first space (so in your example \\IP ADDRESS\NETWORK). check to make sure that the link complete.

Comment: @FrankThomas The link appears complete and as mentioned - the links always work for some users but not all.

Comment: If testing on a normal user's machine by adding a new Outlook profile and configuring the account of a problematic user, can the user in question successfully open the network share?

Comment: @YukiSun The user in question can open the network share.

Comment: @LBTwin, you mean when the user in question logs on another machine, the issue cannot be replicated?

Comment: @YukiSun It's random. Their account works on some machines but not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We observe similar behaviour of Outlook.
\full.host.address\path\ does not work
\IPaddress\path\  does not work
Outlook register error in Application eventlog "Something unexpected happened to this URL" - error 25
Users may copy link to Windows Explorer and it works from there, but not from Outlook.

\host\path\ does work - Outlook just warns it might be dangerous
We think it might be related to some recent Windows or Office365 Updates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be related to the after installing the Outlook Desktop July 11th security updates.

For machines that are affected, try adding those URLs to the Trusted Sites zone.

1. Go to **Windows Settings**.
2. Search for and open **Internet Options**.
3. Click the **Security** tab, then select **Trusted Sites**.
4. Add the URL, UNC, FQDN path that you want to allow to "**Add this website to the zone**".
   For example, add file://server.usa.corp.com

[image]

MS document: [Outlook blocks opening FQDN and IP address hyperlinks after installing protections for Microsoft Outlook Security Feature Bypass Vulnerability released July 11, 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-blocks-opening-fqdn-and-ip-address-hyperlinks-after-installing-protections-for-microsoft-outlook-security-feature-bypass-vulnerability-released-july-11-2023-4a5160b4-76d0-465b-9809-60837bbd35a8).

Similar thread in MS Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336264/how-to-fix-link-to-file-server-in-outlook

Comment: Yep, this solves the problem. Now you can open UNC links and you'll have a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Network shares not properly working in Outlook are caused by Microsoft 365 updates, in our case version 2308 build 16.0.16731.20052, for us, new links (created in new mails) or existing links (older emails) for fileserver shares stopped working. Error was: "Something Unexpected Went Wrong With This URL" error message with the yellow exclamation mark). After reading Yuki Sun explanation and adding the file server to the trusted zone, error message changed to "microsoft has identified a potential security problem" this path could be unsecure, continue?. As far as I know trusted paths can't be added to outlook via GPO (We already have a GPO to add a specific path to the trusted zones in Excel). So, to overcome the problem and letting end points reach network shares on your fileserver via Outlook you could add a GPO to add the server to the trusted zones. See this URL for full details and pictures: [https://blogs.manageengine.com/active-directory/2018/08/02/securing-zone-levels-internet-explorer.html#:~:text=To](https://blogs.manageengine.com/active-directory/2018/08/02/securing-zone-levels-internet-explorer.html#:%7E:text=To) set trusted sites via,Show to edit the list.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1213289)

Comment: I finally stated that I think the problem described in the question is related to latest office updates and could be fixed with coming updates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).